# Find the traffic stats of a specific page in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I use Google Analytics to monitor one of my Websites. However, I have a problem and I cannot monitor the stats with the way I should. What I mean... I have a page which a user can use a link with get parameters to autofill a form.

Let's say that I have a page like this one:

`www.mywebsite.com/mypage`

On the history (and  on realtime stats) I have different stats for:

```
www.mywebsite.com/mypage
www.mywebsite.com/mypage?param=123
www.mywebsite.com/mypage?param=234
www.mywebsite.com/mypage?param=345
...
...
```

There are several parameters and I cannot check them one by one. I would expect a stats page which will present stats for `www.mywebsite.com/mypage` and for any same link with parameters as one page.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/55320)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done using "advanced segments".

1. Click on "+ Add Segment" to your report. [image: add segment]
2. Click on "+ New Segment" (the big red button)  [image: new segment]
3. Name your segment "My Page"
4. Click on "Advanced" -> "Conditions"
5. Add the condition "Page" contains "/mypage"[image: my page segment]
6. Hit the blue "Save" button
7. View any of your reports with this segment applied.

In the future, you will not have to recreate this segment.  It will be available to apply from the "+Add Segment" menu.